# What is the web Google URL to find the directions between 2 coordinates (lat, long)?

Tags: google-maps, url

I am trying to open up google maps in the browser by passing it 4 points.  What is the scheme to launch google maps so it inputs a start coordinate and an end coordinate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not offically documented, but currently this works:

```
https://www.google.de/maps/dir/origin_lat,origin_lng/destination_lat,destination_lng/
```

e.g. Chicago to Detroit:

https://www.google.de/maps/dir/41.87,-87.62/42.33,-83.04/

You may also use addresses:

```
https://www.google.de/maps/dir/origin_address/destination_address/
```

https://www.google.de/maps/dir/Chicago/Detroit/

Answer (score 0):

The URL parameters for this Google API are destination and origin, here you can use adresses or coordinates as values:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=sydney&destination=sydney&key=...
```

but be aware that for this service you need an API key. When using the javascript API you don't need an API key, at least if you don't have too much traffic.